# weird behaviour of AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-keypad

I have a editext and if i enter some text and click back button it shows a dialog asking me whether to discard the changes or not but i wanted to show the keypad on creation of the activity so i added the following line in my oncreateview of fragment

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
```

now when i make changes in my edittext the AlertDialog saying whether you want to discard the changes doesn't show up?

If i remove the line

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
```

from my onCreateView it shows the AlertDialog.

```
    public class EditorFragment extends Fragment implements android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>, EditorActivity.OnBackPressedListener {


    private EditText TaskName, DueDate, DueTime;
private boolean taskChanged = false;
 private View.OnTouchListener onTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            taskChanged = true;
            return false;
        }
    };

 @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_editor, container, false);
       TaskName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.tasknameedittext);
        DueDate = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.duedateedittext);
        DueTime = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.duetimeedittext);

   TaskName.setOnTouchListener(onTouchListener);
        DueDate.setOnTouchListener(onTouchListener);
        DueTime.setOnTouchListener(onTouchListener);
 getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
}
 @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_editor, menu);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.editoractivitydelete:
                showDeleteConfirmationDialog();
                return true;
            case R.id.editoractivitysave:
                saveTask();

                return true;
            case android.R.id.home:
                //up button code
                if (!taskChanged) {
                    NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(getActivity());
                    return true;
                }
                DialogInterface.OnClickListener onClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(getActivity());
                    }
                };

                showUnsavedChangesDialog(onClickListener);
                return true;


        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


 private void showUnsavedChangesDialog(DialogInterface.OnClickListener onClickListener) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setMessage(R.string.discardchanges);
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, onClickListener);
        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if (dialog != null) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }

 @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        ((EditorActivity) getActivity()).setOnBackPressedListener(this);
    }

    //Back Button code
    @Override
    public void doBack() {
        if (!taskChanged) {
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(getActivity());
            return;
        }

        DialogInterface.OnClickListener onClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(getActivity());
            }
        };

        showUnsavedChangesDialog(onClickListener);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell from your question how you are detecting changed state.

How about you try this strategy.

1. Save the state of the contents of editText in onCreate to some member variable.
2. On back button pressed check to see if current contents of editText is same as the member variable you saved onCreate.
3. If they are different, then use that condition to call your method to display alertDialog. Otherwise let user back out.

Example using the above code

```
public class EditorFragment extends Fragment implements android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>, EditorActivity.OnBackPressedListener {


    private EditText TaskName, DueDate, DueTime;
    private String originalTask = "";

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_editor, container, false);
       TaskName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.tasknameedittext);
        DueDate = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.duedateedittext);
        DueTime = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.duetimeedittext);
       originalTask = TaskName.getText().toString();

    TaskName.setOnTouchListener(onTouchListener);
        DueDate.setOnTouchListener(onTouchListener);
        DueTime.setOnTouchListener(onTouchListener);
 getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
}
 @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_editor, menu);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.editoractivitydelete:
                showDeleteConfirmationDialog();
                return true;
            case R.id.editoractivitysave:
                saveTask();

                return true;
            case android.R.id.home:
                //up button code
                if (!taskChanged) {
                    NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(getActivity());
                    return true;
                }
                DialogInterface.OnClickListener onClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(getActivity());
                    }
                };

                showUnsavedChangesDialog(onClickListener);
                return true;


        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


 private void showUnsavedChangesDialog(DialogInterface.OnClickListener onClickListener) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setMessage(R.string.discardchanges);
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, onClickListener);
        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if (dialog != null) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }

 @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        ((EditorActivity) getActivity()).setOnBackPressedListener(this);
    }

    //Back Button code
    @Override
    public void doBack() {
        if (!originalTask.equals(TaskName.getText().toString()))
        {
           NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(getActivity());
           return;
        }

        DialogInterface.OnClickListener onClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(getActivity());
            }
        };

        showUnsavedChangesDialog(onClickListener);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have done the same thing by using a boolean variable to check whether user have changed the state of edittext or not.Below is the code

Comment: Could you please post your code. I didn't have enough karma to comment on your initial post to ask. Then I can assist further

Comment: Instead of using a boolean taskChanged and then setting true when OnTouchListener fires you could try the following.

Instead of your boolean taskChanged. Keep a String member variable that is set to the initial value of your editText onCreateView.

When back is pressed. Check if the string is equal to the text currently in editText

I'll edit the above code with example

Comment: Not working.I think the main culprit is getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
Do you know any other way of showing keypad on activity start up